# Convert hashmap to string

Tags: java, rest, arraylist, hashmap, spring-data-jpa

I am working on a legacy database where modifying the table schema is not an option. Most records are unique but there are some duplicate entries. For that reason I have modified the `RecordRepository.java` interface to perform a `@Query` with map(). Otherwise JPA will return the same data if it thinks it's the same record.

RecordRepository.java:

```
@Query("select new map(field1 as field1, field2 as field2) from Record where year = ?1")
List<Record> findByYear(String year);
```

RecordController.java:

```
@RestController
public class RecordController {
    @Autowired
    private RecordRepository recordRepository;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/record/{year}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public List<Record> recordByYear(@PathVariable("year") String year) {
        List<Record> l = recordRepository.findByYear(year);

        System.out.println(l.getClass());
        System.out.println(l.get(1967));

        return l;
    }
}
```

The output from `getClass()` is `class java.util.ArrayList`. Printing item 1967 from the ArrayList is `{field1=2018-01-15, field2=201801}`.

But when trying to get the string-value of field1 using `String tmp_r = l.get(1967).getField1()` I get the error `java.util.HashMap cannot be cast to Record`.

I have tried various suggestions from SO. My head is spinning, I must be overlooking something simple explanation to this.

Regards
Claus

Comment: "select **new map(field1 as field1, field2 as field2)** from Record ..." is creating a `List<HashMap>` not a `List<Record>` and your repository method `List<Record> findByYear(String year)` needs to return `List<Record>` so it tries to cast each `HashMap` in the resultset to a `Record` which is not possible.

Comment: Aah, I think I need to redo the map() in JPA then. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well `l.getClass()` is an ArrayList, but that doesn't mean that all its elements are Record-s (maybe casts were done somewhere else).

When you call `l.get(1967)` the resulting item is an HashMap (right?), so maybe you can check the actual type of the expression `l.get(1967)` first.

If the map is indexed by Strings, then `String tmp_r = l.get(1967).get("field1")` will print your field.

Comment: The return type in the interface is List<Record>. And wrapped in a map() in JPA. So maybe there is some unpacking I need to do? I tried get("field1") but it does not work.

Comment: I need to rethink the way I get the data. Thank you.

Comment: You lead me in the right direction. I'll add my own answer on how I solved it and award you with the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

Danieles answer, and STaefi's comment, led me in the rigth direction. The solution ended up being quite simple. My error can be attributed to the facts it's been a while I worked with this. I changed the return type in the interface from List to List.

RecordRepository.java:

```
List<HashMap<String, Record>> findByYear(String year);
```

RecordController:

```
List<HashMap<String, Record>> l = recordRepository.findByYear(year);
System.out.println(l.get(1967).get("field1"));
```

will give me the value field1 has.